# Regular expression for a valid temperature value (Celsius)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for a valid temperature value. It has to be in the range "-273.15 °C" to "1000 °C" (but only the numbers).

What should it be?

Comment: `if (t >= -273.15 && t <= 1000)` - why would you use a regex for that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `parseFloat()`.

For example,

```
var temperature = parseFloat("300 °C");
if (temperature > -273.15 && temperature < 1000) {
    console.log("valid temperature")
}
```

Or you can use regex `/(\d+|\d+\.\d+)\s*°C/`:

```
var temperature = "some text 565.34 °C other text".match(/(\d+|\d+\.\d+)\s*°C/)[1]*1;
if (temperature > -273.15 && temperature < 1000) {
    console.log("valid temperature")
}
```